# Is there a word or expression in the Bible that confirms that God can predict the future?

Tags: attributes-of-god, language

I have read about this in a book some time ago and it stuck into my mind. The author was doubting the [divine inspiration nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_inspiration#:%7E:text=All%20scripture%20is%20given%20by,furnished%20unto%20all%20good%20works.&text=The%20word%20%22inspiration%22%20comes%20from,and%20from%20the%20verb%20inspirare.) of the Bible by using the following reasoning:

- Since the Bible is inspired by God who is able [to predict the future](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Comm/stewart_don/faq/10-reasons/reason6-the-bibles-ability-to-predict-the-future.cfm), it should contain some concepts from times long after those parts were written
- There is no such concept in the Bible and the authors use only words (concepts) that are understood by men

I am wondering about the second statement (since it is hard to prove a negative) and it could be simply refuted by finding such a concept. To make it clearer what I am looking is something like the following:

- a word or expression that is very similar to a concept developed (found) by humans a long time after the Bible was written
- that construct would have had no meaning for the writer
- this requires an alphabet, a condition already satisfied considering the languages [the Bible was written with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Hebrew#:%7E:text=Biblical%20Hebrew%20has%20been%20written,used%20the%20Paleo%2DHebrew%20alphabet)

**Question:** Is there a word or expression in the Bible that confirms that God can predict the future?

Comment: Prophecy maybe?

Comment: Isaiah chapter 53 is a pretty good indication as well as Micah 5:2 and a whole lot of Daniel.  Also Job 26:7 "He hangs the earth on nothing."

Comment: That God inspired the Bible writers to correctly predict the future is beyond doubt.  However, all concepts and words in the Bible use the language and idioms of the writers at the time.

Comment: God doesnt predict the future. God creates the future.

Comment: The beginning of the Bible speaks of the world having a beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. And God saw that the light was good. And God separated the light from the darkness. (Genesis 1:3-4) [ESV]

In the context, there is no source of light as the sun and the stars do not come into existence until the fourth day. God simply spoke light into existence. That is to say, God made (i.e. formed, see below) natural light with its physical character. All translations reflect a repetition of the word light: the first spoken by God ("*let there be light*") and the second from the narrator's point of view (*and there was light*). The text confirms there actually was natural light on the first day despite the lack of a physical source when it says ...*and God saw the light...*

The Hebrew of verse 3 begins with the two words, ויאמר אלהים, "*And said God...*" followed by four words, two of which are exactly the same: יהי **אור** ויהי־**אור**. The word, אור is "light." The word before each "light," הָיָה is also the same but is not written in exactly the same form. A literal translation would be: *Said God, "Be light and become light.*" In other words, God made natural light by repeating the word light. If one could hear a recording of the words spoken by God, the word אור would be heard twice.

The significance of repeating light is that natural light exists simultaneously as both a particle and a wave. This is known as [wave-particle duality](https://global.canon/en/technology/s_labo/light/001/11.html#:%7E:text=Light%20Is%20Also%20a%20Particle!&text=Now%20that%20the%20dual%20nature,of%20photons%20is%20a%20wave.). So the literal text reflects a truth of the natural world which was unknown to the writer, and to all early translators. If the true nature of light had been discovered before the Old Testament began to be translated into other languages, all translations would read *And God said, "Be light become light" and God saw that the light was good.*<sup>`1`</sup>

This dual nature of light is implied elsewhere in Scripture:

> I form light... (Isaiah 45:7)
> ...God is light, and in him is no darkness at all. (1 John 1:5)

"Form" light is scientifically the more precise description of natural light with its dual nature. In addition, since natural light travels as a particle, it always "contains" darkness. Thus *God is light in whom there is no darkness* recognizes the particle characteristic of natural light which is distinct from God's light.<sup>`2`</sup>

Finally, Genesis 1:4 states God separated the light from the darkness. This too expresses a physical truth unknown to the writer as light does not interact with dark matter or dark energy: they were separated by a work of God. Separating darkness was repeated on the fourth day so one could say light was separated from dark matter on the first day and from dark energy on the fourth day, or vice versa. The point is after the fourth day (which establishes the conditions we experience) light has been separated from both. Moreover, the writer would not know "darkness" is composed of two different types of physical darkness which would require two acts of separation.<sup>`3`</sup>

Therefore, there are two otherwise inexplicable aspects of the natural world which are described in the Hebrew text of the first day as resulting from God's work.

---

<sub>1.</sub> <sub>A repetition of light is present in Einstein's formula, E=mc<sup>2</sup> where "c" stands for the constant speed of light. Essentially, Einstein was the first to more accurately translate the Hebrew of the Genesis 1:3' he just did so using mathematical terms.</sub>
<sub>2.</sub> <sub>This is consistent with the descriptions of the Transfiguration (cf. [Matthew 17:1-13](http://%3Csub%3E1.%3C/sub%3E%20%3Csub%3EA%20repetition%20of%20light%20is%20present%20in%20Einstein%27s%20formula,%20E=mc%3Csup%3E2%3C/sup%3E%20where%20%22c%22%20stands%20for%20the%20constant%20speed%20of%20light.%20Essentially,%20Einstein%20was%20the%20first%20to%20more%20accurately%20translate%20the%20Hebrew%20of%20the%20Genesis%201:3%27%20he%20just%20did%20so%20using%20mathematical%20terms.%3C/sub%3E), [Mark 9:2-13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%209%3A2-13&version=ESV), and [Luke 9:28-36](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%209%3A28-36&version=ESV)).</sub>
<sub>3.</sub> <sub>Even if one rejects the interpretation of the repetition of light as spoken twice by God, separating light from darkness is undisputed.</sub>

Comment: This is the closest answer to what I am looking for and it is an interesting parallel to Einstein's relativity theory. Thanks.

Comment: @ RevelationLad God did not "create" light, He "formed" light: (Isaiah 45:7)."I form the light, and create darkness: I make peace, and create evil: I the LORD do all these things." If you check all scripture, except some late appearing paraphrases, NOWHERE in scripture does it say that God "created" light, ONLY that He "formed, or transformed" light. If you do not wish to comprehend God's word choices, you will have a hard time of proving the "TRUTH" of God's TRUE WORD. Proper word choice is one very demanding attribute of the WORD of God--it is His "specialty."

Comment: @Alexei Even though you are looking for an answer that parallels Einstein's relativity theory, the idea of "creating energy" is totally contrary to God's law of matter--the one we know as the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics. Yes, God created matter having only darkness upon its face--the waters of Gen. 1:2. However, He formed"--"made"--"transformed" (did not create) the light on Day-One (Isaiah 45:7). Those waters were a type of the WORD of God. Light (potential light) was in the waters (the WORD) , but was "formed" from those waters.. He was "in" that light, and He "was" that light.  (John  1:1-8)

Comment: @BillPorter "Formed" was part of my answer but I have made that more clear. Also no where do I say God created energy. I make the observation that Einstein's mathematical expression should be seen as derived from Genesis 1:3. The point is two-fold. First, modern science claims the creation narrative is a myth. Then science promotes their own theories to account for the natural world; theories which in fact affirm and are derived from the Biblical account of God's work in making the natural world.

Comment: @RevelationLad Well stated. Thanks for all the information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scripture, Isaiah 46:10 (KJV)

> Declaring the end from the beginning, and from ancient times the things that are not yet done, saying, My counsel shall stand, and I will do all my pleasure:

Here is the Hebrew from [StudyBible.info](https://studybible.info/IHOT/isaiah%2046:10):

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Question: Is there a word or expression in the Bible that confirms that God can predict the future?

Answer: Yes.

[Tehillim (Psalms) 139:4] “Before a word is on my tongue, YHVH, you know it completely.” (כִּ֚י אֵ֣ין מִלָּ֣ה בִלְשׁוֹנִ֑י הֵ֥ן יְ֜הֹוָ֗ה יָדַ֥עְתָּ כֻלָּֽהּ)

[Matthew 24:36] “But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father.”

Answer (score 0):

Psalm 139:16 is pretty clear

> Your eyes beheld my unformed substance.
> In your book were written all the days that were formed for me, when none of them as yet existed.

Answer (score 0):

The precept that liquid waters always seek to be located upon the **"earth below"**, whereas gaseous waters always seek to ascend into the **"heaven above"**, is an excellent example that you are looking for. This precept was not fully understood at the time that God divided the single body of waters into two bodies of waters by placing the one (**earthly**) body of waters in the "**midst**" of the entire combined body that was divided, while at the same time, "**under**" that remaining (**heavenly**) body of waters. The Hebrew word, "***mayim***", is a **dual**, not a plural. It is a unique and special Biblical Hebrew term demanding that the waters are to be considered a "**twosome**", yet always used in a singular sense.

On Day-One, a full day before the body of "created" waters was divided, it was **CLEARLY** only a **single** body of waters, yet being that **inherent twosome**--like two ***hands***, required by the Hebrew term, mayim. If it were more than one body on Day-One, there would have been no need to divide it on Day-Two. Moreover, on DAY-Three, one day after dividing those waters by a hammered-out-thin "*firmament*", God "gathered together (into **one** place) **ONLY** those waters under the firmament to "make" "**several plural seas**"--not just two seas"--along with a single dry land earth.

This gathering together to make liquid water seas **LEFT UNTOUCHED** the un-gathered-together waters that were above the inner body of altered matter--the earthly portion of the Day-Two division of matter. Only after that,--on Day-Four--was the outer body of ungathered waters made into lights of heaven, together their stretched-out atmospheres.

Throughout scripture, beginning at Moses, ***mayim***--invisible gaseous waters as well as visible liquid waters--are REPEATEDLY treated as a type of God's eternal spiritual invisible WORD who was also "made visible flesh" on earth at a certain point in time--***this day have I begotten thee***. The prophets reminded us of Genesis One over and over again, .

In Genesis 1:9, the verb phrase "gathered together" is translated from the verb, *qavah*, which means: to wait, look for, hope, and to bind together.

> And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so.

The Hebrew word ***miqveh*** was the masculine noun translated in Gen. 1:10; supra as the gathering together of those invisible gaseous waters to make the several Day-Three visibly manifest liquid-water seas. Miqveh means both (1) hope, ground of hope, things hoped for, outcome, and also (2) collection, collected mass. Well that same word—miqveh—is also used as a noun in Jeremiah 17:13 and is translated as **‘the hope.’** Notice how explicitly that **‘the hope’** applies to Messiah—that **one hoped for**—**that hope of Israel**—that **fountain of living waters**:

> O LORD, the hope (***miqveh***) of Israel, all that forsake thee shall be ashamed, and they that depart from me shall be written in the earth, because they have forsaken the LORD, the fountain of living waters. (My insert)

Notice also that miqveh is clearly pictured as an **earthly** fountain of liquid waters under the firmament because those who forsake Him are written in the earth. So the fountain of gathered together living waters is a type of the LORD—that visible hope of Israel—that visible substance of things that had previously been hoped for—that evidence of Messiah in the flesh not previously seen although promised by the invisible Word of God as spoken by all the prophets. (Hebrews 11:1-3)

The Jewish prophet Isaiah declared that Messiah was to be named Immanuel (God with us) being both the Son of God and the Son of man through Abraham, Judah, and David by being born in the flesh upon the earth of a Jewish virgin—an attention getting sign as we read in Isaiah 7:14:

> Therefore the Lord himself shall give you a sign; Behold, a virgin shall conceive, and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel.

John the Baptist repeatedly showed this type while explaining his liquid water baptism as compared to Jesus' spiritual baptism. Jesus also adamantly compared the liquid waters as a type of the birth of the flesh of man on earth, whereas the spiritual birth was likened to the wind that bloweth, that you can "HEAR", but not "see."

NOWHERE in scripture can you find that liquid waters will be found in heaven on any heavenly planets. I can personally say that though I have lived through the most accelerated time of learning about space, **this truth has held firm**--Liquid waters are found on earth, and gaseous waters are found in heaven. No exceptions. I remember pictures in my science books in the late 1950s showing what they claimed as being "canals" on a certain planet. That pipe-dream fell flat, as have ALL attempts to find an ocean, lake, river, pond, or even a gooey mud puddle containing liquid water on another planet.

Some parts of this answer, together with many more scriptural proofs are outlined in my paper, [God's Day-One Creation, A Type of the WORD of God](https://circumspectnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Gods-Day-Five-Creation.pdf),